# Using beanshell to run java code

Tags: java, string, beanshell

Okay so I have some simple code I would like to run using the beanshell interpreter, and I am trying to figure out how I could do something like:

```
String s = "int x = 5; System.out.println(x);" 
Interpreter i = new Interpreter();
i.eval(s); //THIS
```

Now the real question arises, how could I convert the output of the "i.eval(s)" back to a string so I can use the output elsewhere?

I apologize if this has already been asked or if there is simple documentation somewhere. I could not find anything that helped.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using the following solution.

```
    Interpreter i = new Interpreter(); // Create a new BeanShell interpreter.
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos); 
    PrintStream stdout = System.out; // Save System.out 
    System.setOut(ps); // Set the out to the PrintStream
    try{
        i.eval(s);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return "Error";
    }
    String out = baos.toString(); // Get the output
    System.setOut(stdout); // Reset the output
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, the eval method returns an Object containing the result of evaluation. Try to cast it to String.

Comment: It returns null for me. Trying, 
"Object obj = (String) i.eval(String);"
"Object obj = i.eval(String);"
"String obj = (String) i.eval(String)"
All 3 return null

Comment: Go in debug and watch i.eval(something) without casting it to string.

Answer (score 0):

**Main.java**

```
package org.example; // Your package 

import bsh.EvalError;
import bsh.Interpreter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws EvalError {
        String s = "int x = 5; System.out.println(x);";
        Interpreter i = new Interpreter();
        i.eval(s);
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'org.beanshell:bsh:2.0b5'
```